# Should I add the location of each image to obtain a better geolocation on search engines?

Tags: image, geolocation, tags, seo, alt

I am working on [www.trumblebuildersinc.com](http://www.trumblebuildersinc.com)

- I want the website to rank higher for a keyword such as "general contractor" in the areas I am targeting for potential clients.
- Should I end each image name or alt tag of a house, bathroom, kitchen, etc. with "City,State" in order to rank higher in those targeted regions of the state?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding the geolocation at the end of the alt text will help you rank in search.

Example:   alt="Acme LLP 
Patent Lawyers, Chicago, IL"

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely help with ranking in image search.

On Web search, the effect will be minimal, and could result in negative SEO if you overdo it e.g. if you have a bunch of images with those place name keywords stuffed on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

The alt text should describe the image, it is not a storage place for keyword. If the description of the image includes words that people might use to search for your business, then so be it.

See the [image guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) here